# negative values for frequencies, in package entropy in R

Tags: r, entropy, information-theory

Using the package "entropy" in R, I have a vector y with decimal points and positive and negative values.

Calculating the frequencies, I get positive and negative values corresponding to the positive and negative values of the vector. Why is it so? What should I do?

My aim is to calculate entropy, so negative frequencies will not work for the logarithm.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: How are you counting frequencies? If you're just taking a tally of how many times you observe specific values, the smallest number should be 0.

Comment: yes, this is what I was expecting also. However, I figured out that the command "freqs" does not calculate the frequency of a vector, but the frequency of a number of counts! Is there a command which has as input the vector as it is (with positive and negative values) and gives the frequencies of occurence? I don't want to use bins.. Is there another way?

Comment: It sounds like you want `table()`.

Comment: but my vector contains values such as: 4.322 e-04 and then when I use the table command, what appears is data in pairs of rows, with the first row being an integer (maybe the value without e-04) and a number underneath it (1 or 2, I guess this is the number of occurences). Why are the values converted to integers? and how can I extract the counts and put them in a vector? (Thank you for your help!)

Comment: `table(y)`: The top row is the unique values of `y`. The bottom row is the count of occurrences. Try for `y<-c(4, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0.0004322)`.